# deleting a column from a text file

Tags: windows, notepad++, text-editor

Suppose I have made a text file in notepad++ in the following format :

```
ID  value1  Value2
0    12.1      2
0    13.2      3
1    3.0       4
1    3.1       5
2    4.2       5
3    4.6       6
3    5.8       6
```

is there any way of deleting a entire column at a time?

Answer (score 4):

If you press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while you click and drag in Notepad++, you can highlight blocks that can be columnar. So you could do something like what is depicted in this screenshot:

[image]

Then you could delete that column or do whatever it is you're trying to do to it.

Comment: I have made some edit in the post. Will this system work now? @Malcolm G

Comment: Yes, @user6843794. It should still work. As long as you are able to vertically highlight what you want to delete, it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a column by holding ALT + Mouse Dragging or ALT + Arrow Keys
Additionally, you can use the *Column Editor* feature to insert or delete values into the columns. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

[image: Column Editor]
[image: Column Editor Insert]

Answer (score 0):

Also using a tool like Ultra Edit does this well (Available in any OS Win/Lin/Mac)

Comment: This should be a comment.